# Simple proof of Stirling's formula? Showing $\frac{n!e^n}{n^n \sqrt{2\pi n}}$ monotonly decreasing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to show that $a_n=\frac{n!e^n}{n^n \sqrt{2\pi n}}$ is monotonly decreasing by elementary tools (e. g. without Stirling's formula, Wallis product)?

Reason for this question:
We want to show this form of Stirling's formula
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n! e^n}{n^n\sqrt{n}} = \sqrt{2\pi}
\end{equation}
and let be given the Wallis product for $\pi$.
There is just one unsolved point remaining: the existence of the limit (see below).

Define
\begin{equation}
a_n := \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n! e^n}{n^n\sqrt{n}} \;.
\end{equation}

When replacing $n$ by $2n$ we get

\begin{equation}
a_{2n} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(2n)! e^{2n}}{(2n)^{2n}\sqrt{2n}} \;.
\end{equation}

Then

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(a_n)^2}{a_{2n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(n)!^2 e^{2n}}{n^{2n}n} \frac{(2n)^{2n}\sqrt{2n}}{(2n)! e^{2n}}
= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n!)^2 2^{2n}\sqrt{2}}{(2n)!\sqrt{n}} \;.
\end{equation}

From Wallis product follows directly that the last expression is equal to $\sqrt{2\pi}$.
Hence
\begin{equation}
\frac{(a_n)^2}{a_{2n}} = \sqrt{2\pi}
\end{equation}

If we knew, that $a_n$ converges to $a$, then $\frac{(a_n)^2}{a_{2n}} \to a$.

Hence $a=\sqrt{2\pi}$ and the Stirling formula would be proved.

Is it possible to show that $a_n$ converges elementary e. g. showing that it is decreasing monton and has a lower boundary?

Comment: hint: take $\ln $ and consider the use of a function $f(x)$ to show $f’(x) < 0$....

Comment: @DeepSea Don't see how one would argue that to be elementary, easy, or necessarily true (as far as $f(n)<f(n+1)\implies f'(x)<0$).